# Retrieving the title, artist/author and duration of a .wav file

Tags: java, audioformat, audioinputstream

I am trying to get the properties of a `.wav` file I am using in my Java project using the following code. However when I run this code the methods `format.getProperty("title")`, `format.getProperty("author")`, and `format.getProperty("duration")` all return null. Should I be getting these details in a different way?

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wavFile);
AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
Object[] temp = {false,
        format.getProperty("title"),
        format.getProperty("author"),
        format.getProperty("duration")};
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure .wav files do not contain title or author information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAV files are hard to work with, even though [they can hold several metadata types](http://wavmetadata.blogspot.com.br/). Depending upon the software and encoder used (*16/32-bit PCM*) you can have different configurations for the file and the [Java Sound API](http://www.onjava.com/2004/08/11/javasound-mp3.html) would face problems to read this metadata.

I tried a lot of tools and libs focused in audio metatagging (such as [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/), [jd3lib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jd3lib/), [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic), [Beaglebuddy](http://www.beaglebuddy.com/), etc.) and most of them work fine with MP3 or other audio formats, but not for WAV files.

Apparently, the better one for handling this is [**Jaudiotagger**](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). It's simple, fast and you can accomplish your goal doing something like:

```
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(wavFile);
WavTag tag = (WavTag) f.getTag();

Object[] temp = {false,
        tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE),
        tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST),
        f.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength() // In seconds
};
```

Also, refer the following links:

- [Official repo and installation guidelines](https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/overview)
- [Test class with .wav metadata extraction examples](https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/src/65dcd55dfedee64a93890f114ddba9e025ec2095/srctest/org/jaudiotagger/tag/wav/WavMetadataTest.java#WavMetadataTest.java-35)

> **Note**: The support for this feature was added from version 2.2.4 above. So, always prefer [the latest version](https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/downloads) to evict compatibility problems.